# Warning: #188-D: enumerated type mixed with another type

Tags: c

```
static enum { TYPE = 'T',
                 [...]
} stage = TYPE; //as default
```

Than I'm declaring function this way

```
void type_init(uint16_t position, uint8_t stage_state);
```

and inside that function I want to pass value of stage_state into stage this way:

```
void type_init(uint16_t position, uint8_t stage_state){
     stage = stage_state;
}
```

And that warns me that I have no idea what's going on. What's going on?

Comment: How can you assign a multi-byte `char` to an enumerator? Anyway, just cast to the `enum` type. Whatever compiler is giving this warning hopefully has documentation that explains why it's best to state deliberate intent to convert arbitrary integers to enumerated types. You can do it just fine, but it's best to tell the compiler that you really mean to. Warnings are there to be resolved or bypassed!

Comment: 'type' is a multichar 4-byte literal (with value something like `0x74797065`, depending on your endianess), representing one of the possible values of your anonymous enum, and you are assigning a `uint8_t` value to the field. Unless the goal is winning the annual C obfuscation contest, I would strongly [recommend against programming like this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/).

Comment: my bad, also good to know that enum don't take 4-bytes literal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever compiler is giving this warning hopefully has documentation that explains why it's best to state deliberate intent to convert arbitrary integers to enumerated types. You can do it just fine, but it's best to tell the compiler that you really mean to. Warnings are there to be resolved or bypassed!

So, cast to the `enum` type to tell your compiler you know what you're doing. To do that, you'll need to give its type a name. Here is a working example, which gives me no warnings with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

static enum Stage {
    TYPE = 42
} stage;

int
main()
{
    uint8_t stage_state = 51;
    stage = (enum Stage) stage_state;

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't like having to type `enum State`, look up how to use `typedef` to avoid it.

Comment: @thebusybee I couldn't agree more. I simply used C99 to demonstrate that the code is basic enough to work even for those who for some reason are still stuck on ancient C standards... Be grateful I didn't use C89. [rolls eyes]

Comment: :-D (Well, wait, currently my job is to write an embedded software in C++98... uh-uh)